# Most efficient way to move a few SQL Server tables to SQLite?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, batch-file, sql-server-2000

I have a fairly large SQL Server database; I'd like to pull 4 tables out and dump them directly into an sqlite.db for remote querying (via nightly batch).

I was about to write a script to step through(most likely on a unix host kicked off via cron); but there should be a simpler method to export the tables directly (SQLite not an option in the included DTS Import/Export wizard)

What would the most efficient method of dumping the SQL Server tables to SQLite via batch be?

Comment: Sqlite treats all data as strings - migrating is not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were considering DTS, then you might be able to do so via ODBC.  MSSQL -> ODBC -> Sqlite

http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

Comment: After digging; this seems like it fits best with my existing code and expected data set.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You could export your data from ms-sql with [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) to a text file, and later import this with a bulk import in sqlite. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660320/how-to-automate-a-process-with-the-sqlite3-exe-command-line-tool) question and answers to get an idea how to do this in sqlite.

You could create a batch file and run this with cron, I guess.