# sqlite field separator for importing

Tags: bash, sqlite

I Just started using SQLite for our log processing system where I just import a file in to sqlite database which has '@' as field separator.

If I run the following in SQLite repl

```
$ sqlite3 log.db 
sqlite> .separator "@"
sqlite> .import output log_dump
```

It works [import was successful]. But if I try to do the same via a bash script

```
sqlite log.db '.separator "@"'
sqlite log.db '.import output log_dump'
```

it doesn't. The separator shifts back to '|' and I'm getting an error saying that there are insufficient columns

```
output line 1: expected 12 columns of data but found 1
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660320/how-to-automate-a-process-with-the-sqlite3-exe-command-line-tool in SO via google. As the question's title was not proper couldn't find in the ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass two commands to sqlite at the same time:

```
echo -e '.separator "@"\n.import output log_dump' | sqlite log.db
```