# Does sqlite3 need to be installed on client machine to run batch file?

Tags: c#, sqlite, batch-file

I wanted to create a batch file to import/dump the data in a sqlite database. My concern is, will this batch file run if my client just double click on the batch file without first installing the sqlite3?

I will include the sqlite3.exe inside the same folder as my batch file and database.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried? Seems similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660320/how-to-automate-a-process-with-the-sqlite3-exe-command-line-tool

Comment: Batch files will execute on your client's machine regardless of the SQLLite installation. One does not have anything to do with the other. The commands _inside_ the batch file are another matter.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, i read that question before but not similar problem. I can run the batch in my machine. I'm just wondering if it'll run fine in client's machine if i just provide the sqlite3.exe instead of installing it.

Comment: Hi PhoenixReborn, hope you can clear things up for me here. My batch file will be calling the sqlite3 command. So if the sqlite3.exe is not available in the client machine, how would the command be available? Am i wrong to say that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is an *embedded* database, which means that the typical and recommended way of using it is to compile it into the program.

The `sqlite3.exe` program does not have any dependencies and will run without installation on any machine.

Comment: Hi CL, thanks for the clarification. If you don't mind, i just want to be clear here. So what you are saying is, lets say if i've created a database using sqlite3(let's say the database name is DB.s3db). I then ask me client to copy DB.s3db into his C drive, then i ask him to run the following command at his C drive: **sqlite3 DB.s3db**, it'll run without any issue? Of course in this scenario, he does not have sqlite3 anywhere in his computer. Thanks

Comment: It will run, if `sqlite3.exe` is there.