# How can I automate opening sqlite3.exe shell and running a command, with a single script?

Tags: sqlite, shell, batch-file

I'm looking to run `sqlite3.exe` then enter the following command

```
.open "file:database.db?node=primary&bind=tcp://0.0.0.0:1234"
```

it uses litesync and enables database synchronisation.

However, I have it running on a server that gets restarted weekly, and have to remote in and manually open `sqlite3.exe` and enter that command above.

I'd like to put it all in a script or batch to be able to run at startup (hardmode: run as administrator).

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660320/how-to-automate-a-process-with-the-sqlite3-exe-command-line-tool).

and although helpful it doesn't help me open SQLite and insert the command at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `--help` message, and a little experimentation, this seems to work to me:

```
sqlite3 -cmd '.open "file:database.db?node=primary&bind=tcp://0.0.0.0:1234"'
```

This does the same thing, I think:

```
sqlite3 "file:database.db?node=primary&bind=tcp://0.0.0.0:1234"
```

Comment: I missed a huge step here, for those who have a similar thought. The steps we have to script are.. Open command windows, navigate to sqlite3 folder using cd ("cd C:\litesync\sqliteStuff") then use the command above. Although those didn't work it helped a lot, here's a line that works and i ill paste the script once i make it.
sqlite3 -init .open "file:database.db?node=primary&bind=tcp://0.0.0.0:1234"